# when no_data_found stop the current iteration and resume the next

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a code like below:

```
DECLARE
rec emp%ROWTYPE
BEGIN
<<start_again>>
FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    SELECT emp_index
    INTO   flag
    FROM   m_sme006
    WHERE  emp_id = rec.emp_id
           AND eff_dt = rec.eff_dt
           AND end_dt = rec.end_dt
           AND last_maint_ts > rec.last_maint_ts;
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
      GOTO start_again;
END;
```

Every time the no_data_found exception occurs, I want the execution to go back and continue with next iteration. But it throws the `error PLS-00375: illegal GOTO statement`

Also can i include this line `dbms_output.Put_line('Outside exception block'rec.sme006_index);` in the exception block to see where this happened?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In addition look at my example here - continuing past exception:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109845/identify-date-format-in-plsql/14124573#14124573

Comment: @Art Thanks, It really gives me insight on how to use the exceptions..

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the program flow from the exception block back to the execution block. You need to put the exception block inside the loop, like this:

```
DECLARE
   rec emp%ROWTYPE
BEGIN
FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    BEGIN
       SELECT emp_index
       INTO   flag
       FROM   m_sme006
       WHERE  emp_id = rec.emp_id
              AND eff_dt = rec.eff_dt
              AND end_dt = rec.end_dt
              AND last_maint_ts > rec.last_maint_ts;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN no_data_found THEN
          dbms_output.Put_line('Outside exception block ' || rec.sme006_index);
    END;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE
  rec emp%ROWTYPE
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
    BEGIN
        SELECT emp_index
        INTO   flag
        FROM   m_sme006
        WHERE  emp_id = rec.emp_id
           AND eff_dt = rec.eff_dt
           AND end_dt = rec.end_dt
           AND last_maint_ts > rec.last_maint_ts;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
          -- whatever code you want to log your error
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```